# On Clicking multiple Checkbox resulting into undesired result

Tags: java, android

I would like my checkbox to show correct answer only for 2 options but if selects more than 2 options including the correct options it shows correct answer which is not the desired Result .

```
package com.example.vidit.project3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class question2 extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question2);
}

public void submit2(View v)
{
    CheckBox cb1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c1);
    CheckBox cb2=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c2);
    CheckBox cb3=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c3);
    CheckBox cb4=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c4);



//Show Correct option for only one combination
    if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked())
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Whopiee! Correct Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && cb3.isChecked() && cb4.isChecked())
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && cb3.isChecked())
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() &&  cb4.isChecked())
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}

public void toQuestion3(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,question3.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}



}
```

Yours Sincerely,
Vidit Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your first `if` like this:

```
if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && !cb3.isChecked() && !cb4.isChecked()){
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Whopiee! Correct Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
}
```

You could summarize your code by doing this:

```
boolean correct = cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && !cb3.isChecked() && !cb4.isChecked();
String message = correct ? "Whopiee! Correct Answer" : "Arghh! Incorrect Answer";
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() && !cb3.isChecked() && !cb4.isChecked())
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Whopiee! Correct Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
else
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```